# Composer does not show package version

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I can't find the recently published version 2.4.1 of my package:

```
amk@orange ~$ composer clearcache
Cache directory does not exist (cache-vcs-dir): 
Clearing cache (cache-repo-dir): /home/amk/.cache/composer/repo
Clearing cache (cache-files-dir): /home/amk/.cache/composer/files
Clearing cache (cache-dir): /home/amk/.cache/composer
All caches cleared.
amk@orange ~$ composer show imi/robo-pack -a
No composer.json found in the current directory, showing available packages from packagist.org
name     : imi/robo-pack
descrip. : iMi Package Tasks for Robo task runner
keywords : 
versions : dev-master, 2.4.0, 2.3.0, 2.2.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.0, 1.4.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.0, 1.0.0, 0.3.0, 0.3.0-alpha.1, 0.2.0, 0.1.0, dev-develop
type     : library
```

While 
https://packagist.org/packages/imi/robo-pack is saying:

[image: Packagist]

Is this a outage on packagist.org side or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Now, without any change on my side, the package is shown. So it looks like it was a hick-up on packagist.org